# main() function not recognized

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, program-entry-point, language-lawyer, entry-point

I am writing code for a class I'm taking. I can't post all my code without zeroing out my score for the project but here is the abbreviated code for my driver:

```
    #pragma once
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include "Stack.h"

    using namespace std;

    namespace jack
    {
        int high(char a)
        {
            // My Code
        };

        bool isSameOrHigher(char top, char cur)
        {
            // My Code
        };

        int main()
        {
            // My Code
        };
    };
```

For some reason that I cannot figure out when I compile this code I get the following error:

LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Now, as far as I know this error should only happen if I don't have a main function, which you can see I do actually have. I have tried copying the code from this file into another project, I've tried separating my main function out into another cpp file all by itself (which caused more errors and didn't fix the entry point error), and I have tried re-installing Visual C++ express and starting completely from scratch. My teacher and I have checked all the code in this file before main() (and all the code in the Stack.h file I wrote and included) and there aren't any missing parentheses, semicolons, or any other punctuation. I don't know what else to even try. Thoughts?

Comment: Your teacher didn't see your main in the namespace?

Comment: it's not main that you need.. it's ::main!  create a ::main and you're set.

Answer (score 8):

You need to move `main` outside any namespace.

For anybody who cares about exactly what the standard has to say (§3.6.1/1):

> A program shall contain a **global** function called `main`, which is the designated start of the program.

Edit: for those who also want the last word on what "global" means (§3.3.5/3 in C++03, §3.3.6/3 with nearly identical wording in C++11):

> The outermost declarative region of a translation unit is also a namespace, called the *global namespace*. A name declared in the global namespace has *global namespace scope* (also called *global scope*). [...] Names with global namespace scope are said to be *global*.

Comment: ok, but can you also add reference to the part that says *global function* means function in the :: namespace?  i am sure it is there somewhere (otherwise it would be ambiguous), and since you have it handy...  as it is, one interpretation is that it just need to not be a class member function.

Comment: so actually something that is a little pedantic, but if you have code like.  *void a(); namespace x { void b(); } class c { void d(); }*.  a is a global function.  d is a member function, not a global function.  what is b?  if b is not global and it's not a member function, what do we call it?

Comment: @thang: I'd usually call it `x::b()`. I suppose if you want to be pedantic, it's a free function at namespace scope.

Comment: i guess that works.  non global free function, or just a free function (which would include global and non global), although it is bound to a namespace.  i wonder if the standard defines a name for that.

Answer (score 5):

Take your `main` out of the namespace

Comment: LOL we all commented at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Move the `main` function outside the namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Take your `main` function out of the namespace. Technically your `main` is actually `jack::main` while it is inside the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You should define `main()` only in `global namespace`, not inside any other `namespace`s.